# can I extend the timeout for mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

Using MVC 
I have a text box on my view which allows the user to enter a positive number.
Depending on what number is entered it will either minus or plus the value in the DB.

For some reason the screen timesout and throws the timeout error:

but if i refresh the page, the update is made and checking the db table the update is also correct.

So my Q being can I extend the timeout for running?

Comment: are you getting database timeout error? I think it will be helpful if you paste the exact error.

Comment: If I was you I would first check the insert logic first. Looks like some things after insert keeps either your request or db busy.